# Clasically-simulable MBQC pattern for a BQP computation

Tags: simulation

I'm looking for an example of an MBQC pattern which performs a BQP computation and ideally has been used in research before. The pattern should be classically simulable (i.e. containing in the region of 10-15 qubits) -- this is so I can demonstrate a protocol for running BQP computations in the presence of noise.

Of course I could construct something instead (there's a 15-qubit CNOT pattern for instance), but would rather use an example which has been demonstrated to be useful in previous research.

Thanks!